# What version of kibana I can use in Alibaba Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to use Elastic search(ELK) product of Alibaba Cloud,Now I want to know which version of kibana is supported by Alibaba Cloud for Elastic Search

Answer (score 1):

**Kibana** is an open source data visualization dashboard for Elasticsearch. It provides visualization capabilities on top of the content indexed on an Elasticsearch cluster. Users can create bar, line and scatter plots, or pie charts and maps on top of large volumes of data.
Alibaba Cloud support kibana version **7.4**
In alibaba Cloud kibana gives shape to the data and it is the extensible user interface for configuring and managing all the aspect of the elastic stack

Answer (score 1):

The Kinbana support version is due to Alibaba Elasticsearch version

the version could from V5.5 to V7.5.

the details mapping relationship could refer to the below link
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/149588.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.15.272d1625ASo2s7